# writing ejs in a script is giving me the error 'Expression expected'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a script tag in my show.ejs file, and I have the following line:

```js
<script>
    const post = <%- JSON.stringify(post) %>
</script>
```

I'm getting the error of 'Error Expected' on both the opening and closing ejs tags. I was wondering why this error occurs and if there was anything I'm doing that isn't allowed.

Comment: Are you sure your ejs file is being interpreted as ejs and not a normal html file? Please post the relevant parts of your server code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just have same issue with VS code if you using VS you need to add to end of settings.json in cofiguration of html this line

```
"html.validate.scripts": false,
```

find html in bottom right
[image: find html in bottom right]

then find configure HTML language
[image: then find configure HTML language]
and add line to end of json file
[image: and add line to end of json file]

Comment: Seems to be the best workaround currently, see: [related github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51118#issuecomment-394978232). 
I put it in the workspace settings file `.vscode/settings.json` so I retain the functionality in other projects.

Answer (score 2):

**There are 2 optional ways.**

**1)**

Change the global delimiters of EJS.

```
const ejs = require("ejs");

ejs.delimiter = '/';
ejs.openDelimiter = '[';
ejs.closeDelimiter = ']';
```

Update your script.

```
<script>
const post= [/- JSON.stringify(post) /];
</script>
```

**2)**

Add this property to settings.json in VSCode.

```
"html.validate.scripts": false
```

Change the global delimiters of EJS.

```
const ejs = require("ejs");

ejs.delimiter = '?';
ejs.openDelimiter = '[';
ejs.closeDelimiter = ']';
```

Update your script.

```
<script>
const post= [?- JSON.stringify(post) ?];
</script>
```

**Note: Auto format will work correctly in 2 ways.**

**Note: I prefer the first one because I can use both auto format and scripts validation and I don't need any EJS extension.**